# How to setup and run Conda on Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda, google-cloud

I am interested in using Google Colab for data modeling. How do I install conda, create an environment and run python in a notebook? I did some searching and found some helpful hints, but had several issues with this. I can only get a partially functional environment so far. 
I get stuck in running another cell in the same environment. Seems that switching cells resets the environment back to default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way to get Miniconda working in Google colab. For now, use source activate, not conda activate in the 2nd cell. Still working out the bugs with using conda to activate.

Full Notebook demo here:

https://donaldsrepo.github.io/Notebooks/GoogleColabCondaCreateEnv.html

github with demo notebook:

https://github.com/donaldsrepo/SampleNotebooks/blob/master/CondaCreateEnv/GoogleColabCondaCreateEnv.ipynb

Google uses Python 3.6.9 by default. I created an environment using Python 3.6.10.

Steps to follow:

1. Install miniconda
2. Create a new environment
3. Run some python code to test the environment is being used

Some sample code:

```
# try to get the bare minimum to get a new conda env working
conda_path = ''
try:
    conda_path = !which conda
finally:
    print('')

if (len(conda_path) == 0):
    print('installing miniconda')
    !wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh && bash Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local
    !conda update conda -y -q
    !source /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
    !conda init 
    !conda install -n root _license -y -q
else:
    print('found miniconda')

conda_envs = !conda env list
res = [i for i in conda_envs if 'test36' in i]
if (len(res) == 0):
    print('not found test36 env', len(res))
    !conda create -y -q --name test36 python=3.6
else:
    print('found test36 env', len(res))
```

Next cell:

```
%%bash
source activate test36

python
import sys
# maybe only need this the first time we run this notebook
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

print("Python version")
print(sys.version)
```

Output:

```
Python version
3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  8 2020, 02:54:21) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

Note that version 3.6.10 is the one installed in my personal conda environment. You can also see your new environment here:

[image: Current Google Colab Notebook]

A few things to point out:

1. If you open a new notebook, your new environment does not exist. Seems to be stored in a transient location, similar to docker.

[image: New Google Colab Notebook]

Comment: Hi Donald, I got warning 'source activate myenv' is deprected, and still output shows python points to my default one, not conda's. I think the issue is in ```!conda init``` command that seems not being taken into effect. I tried ```!conda init bash```(you need to specify the shell type) but still no effective. Any comment to help out in successfully activating a conda env in colab ?

Comment: You can ignore the warning for now. Did you change `source activate myenv` to `conda activate myenv`? If so, this example won't work. It will complain about conda init, etc... For now, can you use source activate?

Comment: Does your screen look like the one on this page? 
https://donaldstierman.github.io/Notebooks/CondaCreateEnv.html
If not, where does it start to look different?

Comment: Hi Donald, thank you for your quick reply. I re-run now. Screen look the same. Thing is I am creating an environment out of a yml file like this : `!conda env create -f enviroment.yml` and then run your solution: I confirm it load a python from conda,  not sure if from the environment I create. In fact when I run a script, it says cv2 is not installed, but it was successfully installed with the the yml file (no errors). Puzzled. Here you can find full track of what I've done : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610289/conda-activate-and-conda-init-fail-to-work-in-colab-as-per-june-2020

Comment: I think you have to run everything within one cell. The next cell seems to forget some of the information it knew in the previous cell. Also, if you open a new notebook, all the installations will disappear. I suspect Google Colab is doing something similar to running a docker container. It only exists while you are running it and it reverts back to an empty container. They must be doing something special for the notebook file itself, saving it to persistent disk storage.

Comment: For now, the only option is to create the environment each time, and run all your code in one cell.

Comment: @Hi Donald, I found a difference or smtg to check further in your answer. 

Please run again your notebook. After having source activation of the test environment, check which is the current active one with `!conda env list`. It turns out that it activates the base environment, not the ones you created (test36). Active ones are marked with `*`see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369272/check-what-conda-environment-is-currently-activated   That clarify why I, in my case, modules are not found in spite of having been installed. Can you test which is current active env ?

Comment: I see the * by my new environment. `# conda environments:
#
base                     /usr/local
test36                *  /usr/local/envs/test36`
I updated my page with the new tests, showing that my new environment is the one being used. Just curious, what version of conda can you see? !conda -V  I have 4.8.3

Comment: I checked out your question on stackoverflow. I see you show the version of python that is not the same default that I see. The default one is see is this one: Python version
3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] Maybe you upgraded python in your default Colab environment?

Comment: ++ Paperspace ✓

Answer (score 14):

*Updated Instructions to install Conda on Google Colab Oct 2021*

The process is much simpler with `condacolab` python library

**Steps**

1. Import `condacolab` python library
2. Install `condacolab`

   ```
   !pip install -q condacolab
   import condacolab
   condacolab.install()
   ```
3. Post kernel restart, check condacolab installation

   ```
   import condacolab
   condacolab.check()
   ```

**Environment**

You can update the base environment with an environment file

```
     !conda env update -n base -f environment.yml
```

***Note** : Unfortunately in condacolab only base environment can be used. Avoid creating new environments*

**Few useful links**

- [Help documentation](https://pypi.org/project/condacolab/)
- [Demo notebook in Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c_RGCgQeLHVXlF44LyOFjfUW32CmG6BP)
- [Additional link](https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522)
- Alternatively, you can access [google colab in conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-colab) as well

Comment: OMG thank you so much, i was stuck on this problem for like 2-3 hours until i found your answer :) . Have a nice day!

Comment: Has anyone managed to activate the base environment? I tried the `conda env update -n base -f environment.yml` command and then `conda activate base`, but if gives an error like: "CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run conda init <SHELL_NAME>", but that doesn't work. Running `conda init bash` seems to work fine (but it updates `/root/.bashrc` which doesn't seem right?) but then restarting the kernel and running `conda activate base` gives the same error.

Comment: this works but it takes a long tine.

Answer (score 0):

try my jupyter notebook. Everything is simple and clear. Gintaras Martinaitis.

https://github.com/gintarasmartinaitis/MINICONDA/blob/main/MINICONDA.ipynb