# Conda refuses install install some packages in env.yml

Tags: colab, conda

I have been trying to apply [answer 2 from this tutorial](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/how-to-setup-and-run-conda-on-google-colab) to install conda on Colab. However, in my example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rwbfd/03b7df369a6591ee42659d5b503b53e4/equitransfomertest.ipynb), when I run `source activate` then `conda list`, I only find part of the packages installed.

I am totally confused now by why since I am pretty sure I have followed the tutorial to a t.

Any suggestions are welcomed.